# InfEng.RunQuery(Query).Count

Tags: vb.net, nxbre

I ask the Inference Engine a question as follows, and want to obtain the first Fact, for the first Query (the question consists of 2 Atoms in the Query), if a result is returned.

`strAnswer = IIf(InfEng.RunQuery(Question).Count > 0, InfEng.RunQuery(Question)(0)(0).ToString, "No Answer")`

This throws an error

```
Exception Details: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. 
Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.Parameter name: index"
```

when the Query count = 0. In the 'Watch' window, it evaluates to 0, and has the message: Error & No children, when I open up the evaluated statement. *When the query returns Facts, this works without a hitch.*

I substituted `.Any`, instead of Count, but that also did not work.

When I changed this to a standard `If-Then-End If`, it works in all cases...and with `.Count` & `.Any`

What am I doing incorrectly ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm no VB.NET expert but the fact `InfEng.RunQuery(Question)` appears twice in the `IIf` statement means the query will be executed twice if `.Count > 0`. You don't want this to happen, ie running a query twice for no good reason.

I suggest you assign `InfEng.RunQuery(Question)` to a variable then use this variable in the `IIf` statement.

Comment: Useful tip / good catch. Thanks a lot. Can't vote up, since I don't have the reputation(15) as yet.